# How to create index in PowerDesigner?

Tags: powerdesigner

I know PDM can create index in table, but when I generate PDM from CDM, the index will disappear.

Any better way to create index and keep generate PDM function work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your process... You created a CDM; generated a PDM from it; added an index in the PDM; modified the CDM; and generated again the PDM... and the index disappeared. Correct? Is the checkbox "Preserve modifications" selected in the PDM generation dialog?

Comment: Yes, it work. I try select "Preserve modifications" , the index is still in the PDM. thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

1- When generating PDM, select "Preserve modifications" in the “PDM Generation Option” dialog

[image: 1pic]

2- Comparison Option set not include Table > Indexes Click [Set As Default], next time won’t need to set again.
[image: 2pic]

3- Generate PDM always accept all actions without remove table index. enter image description here
[image: 3pic]

[refrence](http://note.robinks.net/2015/10/how-to-create-index-in-powerdesigner.html)